# Bulk converting MKV files to MP4 with AAC using a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, mp4, aac, mkv

So I have been trying for days to work out how to do this and this site has helped me but I am still stuck.

I basically want to run a batch file and it goes through a folder including all subdirectories and changes the container of all mkv files to mp4 converting the sound to AAC if necessary. Preferably it will create the new mp4 file in the same place with the same name and then delete the mkv.

All I have so far is this which if I place it in a certain folder will create the mp4's in a specified folder called newfiles. I am not sure if I have used libfaac correctly either. Would greatly appreciate any advice. I would have liked to use libfdk_aac but I have tried everything to get it and I cant find it.

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac "Z:\newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, it creates a sub folder called Newfiles and starts creating mp4s. The sound isn't great though.

Comment: So I have sorted the first part, I can now create the mp4 in the same folder by removing the newfiles part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for variable bit rate (VBR):

```
for %%a in (*.mkv) do C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -vcodec copy -c:a libfaac -q:a 100 "%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

> Range for -q:a is 10-500 and is similar to using the -q option in standalone faac. 100 is a good value to try.

---

or try this for average bit rate (ABR):

```
for %%a in (*.mkv) do C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -vcodec copy -c:a libfaac -b:a 192k "%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

[FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide: libfaac](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC#libfaac)

Note that you will not get as good results as with `libfdk_aac`.
The license of libfdk_aac is not compatible with the GPL, so the GPL does not permit distribution of binaries containing code licensed under these licenses when GPL-licensed code is also included. Therefore this encoder has been designated as "non-free", and you cannot download a pre-built ffmpeg that supports this. This can be resolved by compiling ffmpeg yourself. You can do this for example with the help of [this project](https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite).

Comment: Thanks that has really helped with the audio. I've worked out from someone else you helped here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141869/ffmpeg-batch-convert-subfolders) that /r can search through folders. Just trying to adjust that script to fit my needs now.